# Parallel HTTP requests in Angular 4

Tags: angular, rest, http, service

I am building a simple weather app that uses a REST service to display current weather data in any city entered by the user.

The dashboard page should display the current weather in ~5 cities specified by the user.

So my question is - given an array of 5 cities, what is the best way to issue a call to the REST service (via Angular service) for each element in that array.

Here's a code excerpt from my initial attempt:

```js
locations: string[] = ["Seattle", "Woodinville", "Krasnoyarsk", "Stockholm", "Beijing"];

...

ngOnInit() {

    this.locations.forEach(function(element) {
      this.weatherService.getWeather(element).subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    });

  }
```

But this yields an error:
Failed to compile.

c:/Projects/weather-app/src/app/components/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts (19,12): Property 'weatherService' does not exist on type 'void'.

I realize the 'forEach' is not going to work here - but what's the best practice for doing this in ng 4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will `map` locations array in array of Observables,
`forkJoin` will emit value, when all responses are in place

```
Observable
.forkJoin(this.locations
  .map((element) => this.weatherService.getWeather(element))
.subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and answers my question - thanks

Comment: Is there any difference If I use `forkJoin` or simply call the same function in loop iteration?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that using the function keyword instead of an arrow function, you are losing what `this` means. Inside a function using the function keyword, `this` refers to the function and not to your component class.

Modify to something like this:

```
this.locations.forEach(element => {
  this.weatherService.getWeather(element).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Note: You could also consider using `forkJoin` to wrap multiple observables.

You can find docs on it here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

But the example here may be more helpful: [rxjs with multiple forkjoin when doing http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204055/rxjs-with-multiple-forkjoin-when-doing-http-requests)

UPDATE: See improved docs here:

https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin

Comment: Thanks for your answer - yes 'this' was the problem. Will look into using 'forkJoin' as well.

Comment: can you point out the benifits of `forkJoin` or simply calling method in `forEach`?

Comment: With forEach your code needs to subscribe to each Observable. That means you should also unsubscribe from each observable (which is not possible with the code as shown above.) With the forkJoin, you don't have to subscribe to any of the "inner" observables ... only to the "outer" forkJoin.