# How to make async requests from different services [Angular]

Tags: angular, httprequest

I have got 3 services with similar methods that return data from database.
I am using them in my component and want to store each data respond in corresponding
component array. How do i get the rest of data from other services?
I am not really familiar with forkjoin, etc. Would be nice if you give an example.

```
Services:

export class BrandService {
  private url: string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.url = 'http://localhost:3000/brands';
  }

  public getJsonBrands(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
}
__________________________________________
export class ProductService {
  private url: string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.url = 'http://localhost:3000/products';
  }

  public getJsonProducts(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
}
__________________________________________
export class CategoryService {
  private url: string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.url = 'http://localhost:3000/categories';
  }

  public getJsonCategories(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
}


Component: 

export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  productList: Array<any>;
  brandList: Array<any>;
  categoryList: Array<any>;

  constructor(private productService: ProductService, private brandService: BrandService, private categoryService: CategoryService) {
   this.productService.getJsonProducts().subscribe(
     product => {
       this.productList = product;
     })

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}

_______________________________________
Code below doesnt seem to work, i keep getting console error "this.brandService.getJsonBrands is not a function"

ngOnInit() {
    forkJoin(
      this.productService.getJsonProducts(),
      this.brandService.getJsonBrands(),
      this.categoryService.getJsonCategories()
    )
      .subscribe(([res1, res2, res3]) => {
          this.productList = res1;
          this.brandList = res2;
          this.productList = res3;
          console.log(this.productList, this.brandList, this.productList);
      },
        error1 => {
          console.log(error1);
        });
  }
```

Comment: ForkJoin from Rxjs [link](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) and a angular example [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/ElTrOg8NfR3WbbAfjBXQ?p=preview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parallel HTTP requests in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247498/parallel-http-requests-in-angular-4)

Comment: This is just lazy, if you search for "parallel http requests angular" you will find a lot of resources explaining how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe other service like product service and include them in providers

```
    constructor(private productService: ProductService,
                private brandService: BrandService,
                private categoryService: CategoryService) {
        this.productService.getJsonProducts().subscribe(product => {
          this.productList = product;
        })
        this.brandService.getJsonBrands().subscribe(brands=> {
           this.brandList = brands;
        })
        this.CategoryService.getJsonCategories().subscribe(categories=> {
           this.categoryList= categories;
        })
    }
```

Comment: i keep getting an "this.brandService.getJsonBrands is not a function" error

Answer (score 0):

Use ForkJoin or CombineLastest from Rxjs, the difference between the two explained here : [Rxjs: Observable.combineLatest vs Observable.forkJoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797439/rxjs-observable-combinelatest-vs-observable-forkjoin)

```
ngOnInit() {
forkJoin(
      this.productService.getJsonProducts(),
      this.brandService.getJsonBrands(),
      this.categoryService.getJsonCategories() 
    )
    .subscribe(([res1, res2, res3]) => {
      this.productList = res1;
      this.brandList = res2;
      this.categoryList = res3;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `combineLatest` or `forkJoin`. Usage is pretty similar.
But you should unsubscribe from `combineLatest` unlike `forkJoin`.

```
import { Subscription, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

sub: Subscription;
myData: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = combineLatest(
    this.brandService.getJsonBrands,
    this.productService.getJsonProducts,
    this.categoryService.getJsonCategories
  ).subscribe(([brands, products, categories]) => {
    this.myData = {brands, products, categories};
    console.log('this.myData', this.myData);
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

**forkJoin** - When all observables complete, emit the last emitted value from each.

**combineLatest** - When any observable emits a value, emit the latest value from each.

Comment: do i declare "sub" variable after the "myData"(sub:any)?

Comment: "Property 'sub' does not exist on type 'ProductsComponent' " and [brands, products, categories] gets "Type 'Observable<any>' is not an array type". In the console it logs: 
"You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable."

Comment: @BobbyFade I have added- sub: Subscription. Updated answer

Comment: [brands, products, categories] this keeps getting "Type 'Observable<any>' is not an array type"

Comment: @BobbyFade Change type of output in your methods -   Observable<any> to Observable. Or remove it.